# Defining an environment using the collect package

Tags: environments, collect

I want to define an environment `aufgabe` which uses the `collect*` environment from the `collect` package. If I built a file like this (without a custom environment), everything is fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{collect}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\definecollection{aufg}

\newcommand{\aufgabenblatt}{\newpage {\bf \Large Aufgabenblatt} \\[3ex] \includecollection{aufg}}
\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe}

\begin{document}

\begin{aufgabe}%
\begin{collect*}{aufg}{}{}{{\bf\arabic{aufgabe}.%
            Aufgabe:}}{}
    Hund
\end{collect*} %
\end{aufgabe}


\aufgabenblatt
\end{document}
```

The aufgabe with the `collect*` gets collected and is shown by the command `\aufgabenblatt`. But if If try to construct my own command, it does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{collect}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\definecollection{aufg}

\newcommand{\aufgabenblatt}{\newpage {\bf \Large Aufgabenblatt} \\[3ex] \includecollection{aufg}}

\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{aufcollect}{\begin{aufgabe}%
    \@nameuse{collect*}{aufg}{}{}{{\bf\arabic{aufgabe}.%
            Aufgabe:}}{}}{\@nameuse{endcollect*} %
\end{aufgabe}}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{aufcollect}
   Katze
\end{aufcollect}
\aufgabenblatt
\end{document}
```

The use of the `\@nameuse` was encouraged in the package documentation. The error is `"File ended while scanning use of \@tempa."` Any idea what I have done wrongly?

Comment: I fear this is a problem with seeing the right `end` of the collect environment. By the way: `\bf` is outdated for more than 20 years. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}`, please

Comment: That's true. Sometimes I forget which one is deprecated and which one isn't.

Comment: All two - letter font commands are deprecated, i.e. `\bf`, `\it`, `\tt`, `\sl` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the middle `environment` isn't really delimited and the `aufgabe` environment should be used as `\aufgabe` and `\endaufgabe`, wrapping around the collection.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{collect}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\definecollection{aufg}

\newcommand{\aufgabenblatt}{\clearpage {\bfseries \Large Aufgabenblatt} \\[3ex] \includecollection{aufg}}

\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{aufcollect}{%
  \aufgabe
  \@nameuse{collect*}{aufg}{}{}{\bfseries \arabic{aufgabe}.Aufgabe:}{}%
}{%
  \@nameuse{endcollect*} %
  \endaufgabe
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{aufcollect}
Katze
\end{aufcollect}


\begin{aufcollect}
Hund
\end{aufcollect}

\begin{aufcollect}
Igel
\end{aufcollect}


\aufgabenblatt
\end{document}
```

Update:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\collect*}{%
  \def\CE@prefileenv{#4}%
}{%
  \edef\CE@prefileenv{#4}% Preexpand this argument
}{\typeout{Stuff!}}{\typeout{Failed!}}
\makeatother


\theoremstyle{definition}
\definecollection{aufg}

\newcommand{\aufgabenblatt}{\clearpage {\bfseries \Large Aufgabenblatt} \\[3ex] \includecollection{aufg}}

\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{aufcollect}{%
  \aufgabe
  \@nameuse{collect*}{aufg}{}{}{\unexpanded{\bfseries} \arabic{aufgabe}.Aufgabe:}{}%
}{%
  \@nameuse{endcollect*} %
  \endaufgabe
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{aufcollect}
Katze
\end{aufcollect}


\begin{aufcollect}
Hund
\end{aufcollect}

\begin{aufcollect}
Igel
\end{aufcollect}


\aufgabenblatt
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One further problem I noticed: The use of the counter "aufgabe" is wrong. Can I do something to expand it immediately?

Comment: @JFMeier: Which value do you expect?

Comment: I would like the value to be the number of the aufgabe counter in the moment of definition. Otherwise, at the end, the collections contains all elements with the same (last) aufgabe counter. In your example, all elements of Aufgabenblatt are called 3. Aufgabe.

Comment: @JFMeier: See the update -- it's necessary to `pre-expand` the argument, I used a patch for this, since a bunch of `\expandafter\expandafter\....` isn't better. Please note, that some other commands must go unexpanded into the verbatim mode, i.e. `\unexpanded{\bfseries}` and perhaps other statements.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a pleasure to get such fast and accurate answers.

Comment: @JFMeier: Gern geschehen ;-)